# Change XTick in subplot not working

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

I have plenty of subplots I have to load and put all together using Matlab. I want to add personalized Ticks but my approach does not seem to work. My mwe is the following:

```
x = 1:1:1000;
r = rand(1000,1);
my1 = subplot(2,3,1);
my1 = bar(x,sort(r));
title ('This works')
xlabel ('This works too')
xlim ([0 1000])
my = get(gca);
my.XTick = [1 200 499]
```

And this last point does not work. Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get(gca)` returns a `struct` of all graphics properties of the current axes, not the axes handle itself. Any changes made to this `struct` of properties are not mirrored in your actual `axes`. You need to modify the properties of the `axes` directly using `set`

```
set(gca, 'XTick', [1 200 499])
```

Or if you're on 2014b

```
% Don't use get(gca) to get the handle
ax = gca;

% Set the XTick property
ax.XTick = [1 200 499];
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much, I am still not used to the Matlab graphics environement